Terminal hangs while writing into a FIFO file
I have a program running under a systemd service and I'd like to pass some text/commands to it, so I tried doing so with a FIFO file:
.service file
[Unit]
Description=A Minecraft server service!

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.env
WorkingDirectory=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/
ExecStart=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start < /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input
StandardOutput=append:/srv/http/mc/mcserver/mcserver.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

.socket file
[Socket]
ListenFIFO=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input
Service=minecraft.service

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

But when I try to write into the file, (either with echo 'stop (or anything)' > minecraft_input or echo 'stop (or anything)' | tee minecraft_input) it just hangs with no output and nothing gets passed. (FIFO File created using mkfifo and has permissions 664)
EDIT:
I accidentally pasted the wrong code. I also tried this:
.service file
[Unit]
Description=A Minecraft server service!
Requires=minecraft.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.env
WorkingDirectory=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/
ExecStart=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start
StandardOutput=append:/srv/http/mc/mcserver/mcserver.log
StandartInput=socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

.socket file
[Socket]
ListenFIFO=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input
Service=minecraft.service

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

But that doesn't work either. The echo command completes, but nothing happens/passes to the program.

After the echo, what does sudo lsof /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input output? Have you run systemctl daemon-reload after chaning those files?

It works!
And would you guess... I wrote Standart instead of Standard! ;)

See the COMMAND LINES section in the systemd.service(5) man page:

COMMAND LINES
This section describes command line parsing and
variable and specifier   substitutions for ExecStart=, ExecStartPre=,
ExecStartPost=,   ExecReload=, ExecStop=, ExecStopPost=, and
ExecCondition= options.
Multiple command lines may be specified by using the relevant
setting   multiple times.
Each command line is unquoted using the rules described in "Quoting"
section in systemd.syntax(7). The first item becomes the command to
execute, and the subsequent items the arguments.
This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the
meta-characters   and expansions described in the following paragraphs
are understood, and   the expansion of variables is different.
Specifically, redirection using   "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes
using "|", running programs in the   background using "&", and other
elements of shell syntax are not   supported.

So your:

ExecStart=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start < /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input


Actually runs /srv/http/mc/mcserver/start with < and /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input as arguments, not with stdin redirected from /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input.
Here you want your service file to have:
Requires=yourservice.socket

in the [Unit] section, and
StandardInput=socket

in the [Service] section.
The .socket unit (which is the one you want to enable and start) will tell systemd to create the fifo and open it in read+write mode. When some process opens it and writes something to it, systemd will start the ExecStart executable (which here should be just ExecStart=/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start) with its stdin on the socket (which here is a FIFO instead).
Note that as the FIFO is opened in read+write mode, once started, that command will never see EOF on its stdin, and will get the input from all the processes writing to it merged together in the order they write it.
If it terminates for a reason or another, systemd will start a new one next time some process writes to the FIFO. Processes writing to it won't get a SIGPIPE because systemd keeps a fd open on the FIFO itself.

Sorry, seems like I accidentally pasted the wrong code. I guess I was trying other ways to make it work.
My original try was exactly what you said. ExecStart with only the start script and StandardInput socket with a socket listening on a FIFO file. But now, the echo command completes, but nothing passes to the program. (I'll edit the question)

There are a couple of possible issues. First, let's rule out systemd as a factor. What happens if you just run your service manually?
In one command line/window, run
/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start < /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input

Then in another window run your echo commands. Does it work as expected? My guess is, no.
There are at least two other potential problems. First, when the echo stop > minecraft_input command exits, it will cause an EOF to be sent through the FIFO into the start command. That will cause the standard input to the start command to close, which prevents it from receiving more commands. The standard input can't be reopened until the whole service exits and is restarted by systemd.
You can get around this by using tail -F to read from the FIFO, reopening it whenever it closes, like this:
tail -F /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input | \ 
/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start 

Another problem may be that the commands you are sending are too short, and are getting delayed in a buffer. You can turn off buffering by further modifying your server command line to this:
stdbuf -o 0 tail -f /srv/http/mc/mcserver/minecraft_input | \ 
/srv/http/mc/mcserver/start 


This changes standard output from the tail into unbuffered mode. With this change, you should be able to get short commands to your start process via the FIFO successfully.
stdbuf is not a POSIX standard utility, and may not be present on your system by default. You can usually find it in a package called something like GNU Tools.
